# Detecting headset clicks in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to receive some kind of event when the button on a headset connected to the phone is pressed? By default it answers/hangs a call, but I'd like to reuse it for pausing/resuming a media file.